# Web content got messed up when zoom in and out

Tags: css, zooming

When I zoom out or zoom in the browser some of the web content messed up. How to fix this?

Here's the CSS of the home page (first link)

```
.footer-image{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.homeheaderh1{
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
color: #d31716;
margin: -520px 0 0 100px;
/* display: initial; */
line-height: 1em;
}

.homeheaderh3{
font-weight: normal;
margin: -320px 0 0 100px;
position: absolute;
line-height: 1.20em;
}

.homeheaderbutton{
float: left;
margin: -220px 0 0 100px;
position: absolute;
}

.homeheaderp{
float: left;
margin: -60px 0 0 100px;
position: absolute;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's the CSS of 2nd link

```
padding-top: 10px;
margin: -550px 0 0 500px;
color: #FFF;
position: absolute;

margin: -450px 0 0 400px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 0.10em;
position: absolute;
font-weight: 300;
```

Here's the pages where the web contents are messed.

http://bit.ly/1KJjaOZ

http://bit.ly/1KCVhJv

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D please see the updated question

Comment: ...and the HTML? It might be better if you made a demo. That said, you can't use `float` **and** `position:absolute` at the same time...pick one, not both. Also absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: what is the best way to display the text in front of an image?

Answer (score 0):

When I view the source in the browser
view-source:http://homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/products-promos/standard-loan/

on line 168 it says

```
<div style="width: 115.80%;">
```

Usually I would avoid setting widths to greater than 100%, because then, it and all it's contents inherit that width, often resulting in the content not fitting on the screen/container.

As the CSS is inline, and not coming from a CSS style sheet, this could be trickier to fix. You need to find out 
- Where that style is coming from, and it might also be useful to know
- Why is it there? (too often I 'fix' one thing, only to break 10 more. This is especially true of CMS themes) But nonetheless I would go with 100% width (or less, e.g. with margins also). If that breaks stuff temporarily, I would just work with it, fixing whatever gets broken, because otherwise you'll be layering fixes (most of which may be unnecessary), on top, all because of, e.g. one bad fix like the 115% width container.

As far as responsive CSS in general is concerned, look into 'media queries', and best practices, e.g. 'mobile first'.

Comment: I already remove it but the web content of that page is messed up

Comment: That was one example of multiple problems that I believe are causing your layout to break at various sizes and zoom levels. It is a lot of trial and error and testing to make a site properly responsive, but, that's the whole point in using a responsive theme: so you don't have to think about such things. But sometimes you have a plugin or module and you will need to tweek the CSS. I use the browser's developer tools to switch rules on and off (or just tweek them) if I suspect they might be causing layout issues. Then delete, change or override if you must to achieve the results you want.